# Delphi: capture exception into TTask and raise to main thread

Tags: delphi

I want catch the exception raised into TTask from the main form/main thread

```
var
    aTasks: array of ITask;
begin
    Setlength(aTasks, 2);

    aTasks[0] := TTask.Create(procedure begin
        raise Exception.Create('Error1');
    end);
    aTasks[0].Start;

    aTasks[1] := TTask.Create(procedure begin
        raise Exception.Create('Error2');
    end);
    aTasks[1].Start;

    TTask.WaitForAll(aTasks);
end;
```

Into the main form (main thread) i see this:

[image]

I have tried to catch the exception and re-raise into main thread

```
var
    aTasks: array of ITask;
begin
    Setlength(aTasks, 2);

    aTasks[0] := TTask.Create(procedure begin
        try
            raise Exception.Create('Error1');
        except on E : Exception do 
            begin
                TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread, procedure
                begin
                    raise E;
                end);
            end;
        end;
    end);
    aTasks[0].Start;

    aTasks[1] := TTask.Create(procedure begin
        try
            raise Exception.Create('Error2');
        except on E : Exception do 
            begin
                TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread, procedure
                begin
                    raise E;
                end);
            end;
        end;
    end);
    aTasks[1].Start;

    TTask.WaitForAll(aTasks);

end;
```

but into the main form i see this:

[image]

How catch and re-raise thread exception to main thread?

**UPDATE**

maybe i have found the correct way using `AcquireExceptionObject`:

```
var
    aTasks: array of ITask;
begin
  Setlength(aTasks, 2);

  aTasks[0] := TTask.Create(procedure
  var
      CapturedException : Exception;
  begin
      try
          raise Exception.Create('Error1');
      except
          CapturedException := AcquireExceptionObject;
          TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread, procedure begin
              raise CapturedException;
          end);
      end;
  end);
  aTasks[0].Start;

  aTasks[1] := TTask.Create(procedure
  var
      CapturedException : Exception;
  begin
      try
          raise Exception.Create('Error2');
      except
          CapturedException := AcquireExceptionObject;
          TThread.Queue(TThread.CurrentThread, procedure begin
              raise CapturedException;
          end);
      end;
  end);
  aTasks[1].Start;

  TTask.WaitForAll(aTasks);
end;
```

now i see the correct error:

[image]

it is the standard way for propagate the error to the main thread?

Comment: That looks good, but it would be even better to use `ExceptAddr` to capture the original exception raise address, and then reraise the exception using the `raise at` syntax.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  i don't understand how make it, i have tried: `ExceptAddrPointer := ExceptAddr; raise Exception.CreateRes(@ExceptAddrPointer ) at ReturnAddress;` but now i see a dialog with chinese char... (more readable: https://pastebin.com/aH8JxTgD)

Comment: `raise CapturedException at ...`

Comment: don't compile: E2021 Class type required

Comment: Compiles fine here, how is your code different from mine? Anyway, you'd be better learning how to use the raise at syntax away from tasks, and then once you understand it, introduce tasks and capture.

Comment: this is the code https://pastebin.com/7wipUBhA

Comment: Yes, you have to capture the return address at the same time as you capture the exception. Think about how `ExceptAddr` is implemented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TTask.WaitForAll()` waits for all of the specified tasks to complete. If any of those tasks end due to an uncaught exception, `WaitForAll()` collects all of the exceptions and raises an [`EAggregateException`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.EAggregateException) into your code:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ar : TArray<iTask>;
begin
  SetLength(ar, 3);
  ar[0] := TTask.Run(procedure begin
    TTask.CurrentTask.Wait(100);
    raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
  end);
  ar[1] := TTask.Run(procedure begin
    TTask.CurrentTask.Wait(100);
    raise Exception.Create('Another Error Message');
  end);
  ar[2] := TTask.Run(procedure begin
    TTask.CurrentTask.Wait(100);
    raise Exception.Create('A Third Error Message');
  end);

  try
    TTask.WaitForAll(ar);
  except
     on E: EAggregateException do ShowMessage(E.ToString);
  end;
//
//  [Dialog Content]
//  One or more errors occurred
//  Error Message
//  Another Error Message
//  A Third Error Message
//  [OK]
end;
```

[`EAggregateException`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.EAggregateException) has public `Count` and `InnerExceptions[]` properties if you want to access the individual exceptions directly.